# how to save new file every iteration

Tags: scheme

I want to create a new file every iteration in a macro code.

I tried to enter a count variable into the file name, but it isn't interpreted like a variable.

```
(define xStart -10 )
(define xFinish 10 )
(define xIncrement 8 )

(define yStart -10 )
(define yFinish 10 )
(define yIncrement 8 )
(define count 0 )

(do ( (xValue  xStart  (+ xValue  xIncrement ) ) )
    ( (> xValue  xFinish ) xValue )
  (do ( (yValue  yStart  (+ yValue  yIncrement ) ) )
      ( (> yValue  yFinish ) yValue ) 
    (+ count 1)
    (edit:move (entity:get-by-name "source") xValue yValue -50)
    (raytrace:all-sources)
    (edit:select (cadr (entity:faces (entity:get-by-name "Block 1"))))
    (analysis:irradiance)
    (analysis:irradiance-save "Z:/shadow/maps/.txt")
    (analysis:irradiance-close)
    (display: count)    
    )
  )
```

Comment: Where is the macro?

Comment: Macros are code transformations so it is to abstract syntax. You probably should make it a procedure if you want it to handle runtime bindings and not code.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`number->string`](https://practical-scheme.net/wiliki/schemexref.cgi?number-%3Estring) converts a number into a string. And the function [`string-append`](https://practical-scheme.net/wiliki/schemexref.cgi?string-append) appends strings.

```
(analysis:irradiance-save (string-append "Z:/shadow/maps/" 
                                         (number->string count) 
                                         ".txt"))
```

But `(+ count 1)` does nothing. You have to set `count` to the new value.

```
(set! count (+ count 1))
```

Comment: thenk's. i'll try it.